# Ruby on Rails RSpec wipes the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm kinda new to RSpec.

I wanted to run some example Rspec spec ( using *rake spec* command), having

> config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

in configuration file, as it was recommended in some manual.

But, it still wipes the database and it just frustrates me, cause I had sensitive data in it and now it's all gone. Who the hell actually came up with an idea of clearing the database during the testing ?

How to avoid this behaviour ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transactions are there to ensure your test database stays clean so that your tests stay clean and predictable. You should be using them. To turn them off for singular example groups, use `self.use_transactional_fixtures = false` after the describe line. You will however if you do this need a `after(:each)` block that cleans up afterwards.

I don't understand why you have sensitive data in your test database, sounds like you're doing something wrong there.

Comment: So you are to say I cannot turn this feature OFF completely ?

Comment: And what should I do about it ? Hm ? If, for example, my web-application is already up and running, what should I do about it ? Test some new feature and get all the data wiped ? Or what ?

Comment: You should be able to use the setting you used to turn it off, but if it's still clearing data sounds like you've got something hooked up wrong. I would really suggest you keep it on unless your clearing the entire DB out yourself after tests. If this isn't acceptable your doing something very wrong and you shouldn't bother writing tests with the setup you've got as they won't be reliable.

Comment: The test database should be separate from your development and production ones.

Comment: And what possibly I could be doing wrong, if there is literally 1 line of configuration and thats all.

Comment: Maybe it is something wrong with using mysql2 gem ? Or running RoR on Windows ? I still don't get it ...

Comment: @Dmitri What's in your spec_helper.rb? Do you have the `ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'` line inside it?

Comment: Windows might do it, but can you post your gemfile? What have you done beside standard bootstrapping commands for rails and rspec and application code? I also suggest you use SQLite for your dev and test DBs. What I think you might have done is point all three environments to the one database. Can you post your database config too (remove any sensitive info of course)

Comment: Really thinking about it, sounds like your only using 1 DB for all the environments. You should check that and post the DB config.

Comment: Well, actually I have them pointed to the same DB ? Is it incorrect ? I should use 3 (2) separate for each of them ?

Comment: Ah. Stupid me. Is there any way to easily copy existing DB ? And to have future migrations to all of them ?

Comment: Look up the SQL commands on W3Schools. Basically setup a development DB test DB and production config you set to environment variables so you can set them on the server and the actual details are kept out of your source control. In a non-sarcastic as non-undermining way possible, you should run through some more books and tutorials. I would suggest the RSpec book from pragmatic books. You should also learn about Heroku, read through their docs, it teaches you great ways to configure and deploy your app properly. Also learn about Capistrano, and watch LOTS of Railscasts by Ryan Bates.